# How do I display long lists of data in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

We are working on a phonegap app and are running into limitations when showing lists of size around 200 or more. We've found iScroll to be a pretty crappy experience at this size and would like to show thousands of items in a list possibly. Does anyone know of any way to display lists in PhoneGap without this scale limitation?

Comment: we have implemeted iScroll to load a result length == 4500 and it works very well. Cant share the code thou, sorry for that. but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another scrollers(such as [Scrollview](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview))

Or if your needs accepts it you can switch listview to collapsible set so it would display less items in one time